# getting two sets of values from a hashmap into two arrays, fast and easy

Tags: java, android, arrays, collections

how in an easy and fast way can I get the two sets of values from a hashmap and load them into two separate arrays? ordering is not important.

example from the hashmap

```
 HashMap<Integer, String> testHash = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
 testHash.put(666, "skullCrusher");
 testHash.put(808, "octabon");
 testHash.put(69, "bloodyHymen");
 testHash.put(23, "chopSticks");
 testHash.pot(100, "prolapse");

ArrayList<Integer> array1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

ArrayList<String> array2 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

the resulting ArrayLists would look like this, and items can be in any order

```
 array1 [666, 808, 69, 23, 100]

 array2 [skullCrusher, octabon, bloodyHymen, chopSticks, prolapse]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add the keys of the map to a specific list, use:

```
list.addAll(map.keySet());
```

And for the values:

```
list.addAll(map.values());
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the order will be the same for both of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(testHash.keySet());
List<String>  values = new ArrayList<String>(testHash.values());
```

If the `List`s already exists , then :

```
ArrayList<Integer> array1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<String> array2 = new ArrayList<String>();
array1.addAll(testHash.keySet());
array2.addAll(testHash.values());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want particularly arrays:

```
List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(testHash.keySet());
List<String>  values = new ArrayList<String>(testHash.values());
```

Then:

```
Integer[] ar1 = keys.toArray(new Integer[keys.size()]);
String[] ar2 = values.toArray(new String[values.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

May this help you:

```
ArrayList<Integer> array1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<String> array2 = new ArrayList<String>();

array1.addAll(testHash.keySet());
array2.addAll(testHash.values());
```